# ERROR 403: Forbidden

Tags: linux, http, centos, wget

When I use agent of my pc run command:

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36" hmksq.ae
```

I get this out:

> http://hmksq.ae/ Resolving hmksq.ae (hmksq.ae)... 104.27.132.131,
>   104.27.133.131 Connecting to hmksq.ae (hmksq.ae)|104.27.132.131|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
>   2016-02-21 02:04:51 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

The server when i try to do `wget` command is a Centos 7, I know I'm using a windows 10 agent but I do not think it make any difference.

How I can solve this?

Comment: Command seems to work fine for me. You should troubleshoot a bit more before posting.

Answer (score 0):

my result:

```
    wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36" hmksq.ae
--2016-02-20 23:27:20--  http://hmksq.ae/
Resolving hmksq.ae (hmksq.ae)... 104.27.132.131, 104.27.133.131
Connecting to hmksq.ae (hmksq.ae)|104.27.132.131|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://hmksq.ae/ [following]
--2016-02-20 23:27:22--  https://hmksq.ae/
Connecting to hmksq.ae (hmksq.ae)|104.27.132.131|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html
```

Comment: So what can be the problem? if I make wget on my site or other sites works without problems.